# How to keep constant arrow scale with consecutive plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I plan to draw a sequence of figures with Matplotlib, each consisting of the field of a certain time frame. I used quiver to generate vector graph, but I want to keep the vector scale to be constant across these figures (in order to make it coherent so that an animation could be constructed later). The code I used is as follows. But I find it impossible to keep the scale to be constant. It seems to me that each time the quiver function is called, a new handle to the quiver graph is created. Thanks for any help in clearing out how to use quiver to achieve this.

```
m = Basemap(projection='nplaea',boundinglat=60,lon_0=-44,resolution='l')
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='0.7')

im = m.pcolormesh(TLON,TLAT,aice,shading='flat',cmap=plt.cm.Blues,latlon=True)
wd = m.quiver(ULON,ULAT,uvel,vvel,color=[0.8,0.2,0.2],latlon=True)

qk = plt.quiverkey(wd, 0.9, 0.9, 0.005, '10 cm/s', labelpos='W')

m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,99.,30.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,180.,60.))
```

Comment: Could you clarify a bit: `quiver` should draw the vectors with the lengths you determine (`uvel` and `vvel`), there is no scaling. Your example cannot be reproduced due to lack of data, but maybe you could create a self-sufficient example or even paste some images of what goes wrong.